# atom-typescript in Atom does not catch errors or show syntax colors in typescript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I'm using the Atom editor with atom-typescript on Windows 10. In late January, something changed and my typescript files ( .ts) no longer have color indicators for syntax. Atom shows them entirely in black and white. My html and json files display with colored syntax. This is only a typescript file problem. When I change syntax themes, the html and json displays change, but not the .ts file displays.

I'm using the One Light syntax and UI theme.  My typescript version is current at 1.7.5.  I'm using angular2@2.0.0-beta.3.  I have typings ( d.ts) files.

With further testing, I found that atom-typescript does not find errors when I purposely introduce and save them. For example, this code

```
import { XComponent, ZDirective } from "angular2/core";
```

triggers no errors and the green message at the bottom says "No errors"

What has gone wrong with atom-typescript in my editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking the Settings / Packages page, I noticed that atom-typescript had version: undefined.  I uninstalled the package and reinstalled it. Everything works fine now. Apparantly, the late January update created some failure, maybe on my PC, that was not recognized and no Atom failure message displayed. But it works now.